# SimpleDateFormat Parsing error with AM/PM

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse input string date to Date. it is unable to detect AM/PM tag in the input.
It should add time to specified date and return date.
But its unable to parse AM/PM tag.
03:00 PM is parsed to 03:00:00 in Date. It should be 15:00:00.

output: 
    Date : Tue Dec 22 03:00:00 UTC 2015
    Calender : Tue Dec 22 11:15:00 UTC 2015
    Result : 2015-12-22 11:15 AM

Am I using wrong date format?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Result : "+Main.addHoursToDate("2015-12-22 03:00 `enter code here`PM",8,15,0));
   }

   public static String addHoursToDate(String date, int hoursToAdd, int minsToAdd, int secToAdd){
        String result = "";
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa");
            Date dt = sdf.parse(date);

            System.out.println("Date : " + dt.toString());

            Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
            cl.setTime(dt);
            cl.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursToAdd);
            cl.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minsToAdd);
            cl.add(Calendar.SECOND, secToAdd);

            SimpleDateFormat dfCal = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

            result = Main.formatDate(cl.getTime().toString(),"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa");

            System.out.println("Calender : " + cl.getTime().toString());

        }catch(Exception e){
            return e.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }

  public static String formatDate(String date, String currentFormat, String requiredFormat) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat currentFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
            Date currentDate = currentFormatter.parse(date);

            flag = date.equals(currentFormatter.format(currentDate));
            if (!flag){
                throw new Exception();  // We are throwing this exception because the date has been parsed "successfully"  
                // but still we are not sure that it has been parsed "correctly"!!!
            }
            SimpleDateFormat requiredFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat);
            result = requiredFormatter.format(currentDate);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "";
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using the new datetime library in java 8 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also keep your date-times in `LocalDateTime` variables and parameters, not in strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got Answer myself:

I need to use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa");
```

H : is used for 24 hour notation.

refer to
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thank you, this was so hard to spot! Learnt to read the docs more carefully